# How to do proper and responsive Image Grid view with display:flex

Tags: html, css, grid, css-float, flexbox

I am pretty confused with `display:flex` that how to get responsive image grid like this..

Thanks in advance. I have tried many StackOverflow answer but it didn't worked

Right now I have Layout like this...

[image]

But i want my layout like this ...
[image]

Html code:

```
<div class="makeExploreCenter">
    <div class="explorePost">
        <img src="skyline-buildings-new-york-skyscrapers.jpg" />
        <div class="likesdetails">
            <div class="propicthumnail">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="explorePost">
        <img src="url.jpg" />
        <div class="likesdetails">
            <div class="propicthumnail">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="explorePost">
        <img src="ymbpp1l.jpg" />
        <div class="likesdetails">
            <div class="propicthumnail">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="explorePost">
        <img src="skyline-buildings-new-york-skyscrapers.jpg" />
        <div class="likesdetails">
            <div class="propicthumnail">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="explorePost">
        <img src="url.jpg" />
        <div class="likesdetails">
            <div class="propicthumnail">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="explorePost">
        <img src="ymbpp1l.jpg" />
        <div class="likesdetails">
            <div class="propicthumnail">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS code

```
.makeExploreCenter{
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap ;
    justify-content: center; /* align horizontal */
    align-items: center; /* align vertical */
}
.explorePost{
    text-align: center;
    margin: 5px;
    max-width: 300px;
    min-width: 300px;
    align-self: flex-start;
    background: #545454;
}
.explorePost img{
    max-height: 60vh;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 70vh;
}
.likesdetails{
    width: 100%;
    height: 44px;
    background: #FAFAFA;
    margin-top: -3px;
    overflow: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a framework like bootstrap will make life easier.

Bootstrap grid system can achieve that easily.

Comment: No @NingJi I wanted to learn these things....

Comment: http://codepen.io/githubitsme/pen/NbarmP/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `flex-diretion: column` property to achieve that effect. See the following example:

```css
.grid{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
  list-style:none;
}

img{
  width:100px;
  height:auto;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="grid">
  <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/140/"/></li>
  <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/150/"/></li>
  <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/125/"/></li>
  <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/160/"/></li>
  <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/90/"/></li>
  <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/130/"/></li>
  <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/52/"/></li>
  <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/159/"/></li>
  <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/60/"/></li>
  <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/69/"/></li>
  <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/85/"/></li>
</ul>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aBLvyJ)

Comment: Not Working !!! It gives me total grid align vartically

Comment: @Nane What browser are you using?

Comment: Flex box is supported by Chrome from version 29 (2013).

Comment: http://codepen.io/githubitsme/pen/NbarmP/

Answer (score 0):

You may do it with `float`

**Example**:

```
---- first div ---- ---- second div --- -------AND-----
4G3Y5B6GBY3G7W10P-- ----5G5W5E6B10P10W- ----SO---------
Picture------------ ----Picture-------- -------ON------
------------------- ------------------- --MORE PICTURES
The text related to Content related to- --MORE TEXT----
this--------------- this--------------- ----MORE SPACE-
----Another picture ----Another picture ---Another-----
3B6G6B7GYB3G7W10P-- ----6B7B8B7WBG10YP- ---content-----
Picture------------ ---Picture--------- Modern content-
------------------- ------------------- ---------------
The text related to Related to picture- ---------------
the another picture above-------------- Whatever-------
-- end first div -- -- end second div-- ---------------
```

**Real example**:

*CSS:*

```
    .grid0, .grid1{float:left;margin-right:30px;}
```

*HTML:*

```
    <div class='maingrid'>
    <div class='grid0'>
    <img src='http://lorempixel.com/100/140/' style='width:100px; height:100px;' /><br>
    The text to the picture number 1.0<br>
    <img src='http://lorempixel.com/100/140/' style='width:100px;height:100px;' /><br>
    The text to the picture number 1.1
    </div>
    <div class='grid1'>
    <img src='http://lorempixel.com/100/150/' style='width:100px;height:100px;' /><br>
    The text to the picture number 2.0<br>
    <img src='http://lorempixel.com/100/140/' style='width:100px;height:100px;' /><br>
    The text to the picture number 2.1
    </div>
    <div class='grid2'>
    <img src='http://lorempixel.com/100/125/' style='width:100px;height:100px;' /><br>
    The text to the picture number 3.1<br>
    <img src='http://lorempixel.com/100/140/' style='width:100px;height:100px;' /><br>
    The text to the picture number 3.1
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Could you Pls post Any Example

Comment: http://codepen.io/githubitsme/pen/NbarmP/

Comment: Great, you have it @Nane